# Is Spring's @Value annotation part of internationalization?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, annotations

I am working on a project where internationalized messages are retrieved using the @Value annotation.
e.g.:

```
@Value("${email.newUser.subject}")
private String NEW_USER_SUBJECT;

@Value("${email.newUser.message}")
private String NEW_USER_MESSAGE;
```

However, as part of my investigation, it appears that the @Value annotation is used to get a property from a property file and does not link into to automatic lookup of the correct version of the message.properties. Therefore as I understand it, this is only working by coincidence because we have currently only a single message.properties file.

Can anyone in the know tell me if I have the correct understanding of the situation?

Comment: `@Value` does nothing with I18N it is used for static configuration not for dynamic/locale based configuration. If you want to have I18N properties inject a `MessageSource` and do a lookup each time you need a property.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your comment.  I have made it into a reply in case it is useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is No, the @Value annotation is not part of Internationalization.  It's use in conjunction with Internationalization is an error and will break when you try to change the Local.